# Determining if a new table object overlaps an existing one

Tags: vba, excel

Take a look at the code below. When I add a new table object (ListObject) to my worksheet I would like to check if the specified range doesn't overlap another existing table. Can this be easily done, or do I need to iterate through all existing tables and verify their range coordinates?

```
Sub TableTest()
    Dim TableObj As ListObject
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    ' How can I check if the range isn't overlapping another table before adding it?
    Set TableObj = WS.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("C5:F8"))
End Sub
```

The code above will raise an error if there is an overlapping table object in the worksheet (e.g. at range A1:D6).

Comment: As you said, you need to loop through your tables, check their ranges, and then see if it falls within your coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, checking the known range and the new range with `Intersect()`:

```
Sub TableTest()
    Dim TableObj As ListObject
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    With WS    
        If Intersect(.Range("C5:F8"), .Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
            Set TableObj = WS.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("C5:F8"))
        Else
            Debug.Print "They are intersecting"
        End If    
    End With    
End Sub
```

---

If you want to make the code a bit more flexible, with no predefined ranges for the tables, you may check for the intersect of the range of all tables and the new range:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim tableObj As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim checkRange As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        For Each tableObj In ws.ListObjects
            If checkRange Is Nothing Then
                Set checkRange = tableObj.Range
            Else
                Set checkRange = Union(checkRange, tableObj.Range)
            End If
        Next tableObj

        If Intersect(.Range("C5:F8"), checkRange) Is Nothing Then
            Set tableObj = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("C5:F8"))
        Else
            Debug.Print "They are intersecting!"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

In the code above `checkRange` is the range, which unites all the ranges, over which there is a table.

Comment: this is not the question, read his post again, especially the last sentence before his code

Comment: @ShaiRado - in a way - yes, but it depends what you read. I have considered the comment `How can I check if the range isn't overlapping another table before adding it?`

Comment: But he added `Can this be easily done, or do I need to iterate through all existing tables and verify their range coordinates?` which means he is familiar with this method

Comment: @ShaiRado - in a way true, but my method is one step further - it unites the tables in one range and checks vs. this range. Thus this check is carried out once.